# How to set environment variables

Tags: environment-variables

Say, I would like to change my editor system-wide to `nano`. I was doing this with

`echo 'export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano' >> /etc/bashrc`

[As I learned](https://serverfault.com/questions/586922/how-do-i-restore-the-default-bashrc), it was a bad idea, because if you accidentally omit one `>`, you will overwrite `bashrc` and won't be able to log in. In addition to being error-prone, is this in any other way a bad idea and which way is better?

Comment: I've said it before but I'll say it again. You are way out of your depth. You need education (which is not our mission), not a Q&A site. Please spend considerably more time researching what you want to do before asking.

Comment: @Iain Is there anything wrong if this question will be properly answered on a public Q&A site? I can see here only public benefit, as well as my education.

Comment: Sad, harsh and true,  cluelesness demonstrated on the scale that you do, devalues the site for the professionals that it is intended for. You are way over your head, perhaps U&L or SU may be better places for you to ask your questions.

Comment: @Iain Probably you are right; this particular question should be on U&L.

Answer (score 4):

Actually edit the file with an editor like nano, or vim.

Answer (score 4):

You can add system-wide environment variables in the file `/etc/environment` instead of adding commands to `/etc/bashrc`.

The entries would then be like

```
FOO=bar
BAZ=quux
```

The rest of your question pretty much comes down to "how to edit a file without messing it up", which to some degree comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Is it ok that `/etc/environment` is empty by default?

Comment: That just means that it doesn't change any environment variables.