# Permanently enable a SCL

Tags: centos, centos7, php56, scl

Is there a way that I can permanently enable a SCL?

I've installed `rh-php56`, and I would like to make sure that it is loaded every time I ssh into my machine.

I am currently running CentOS 7.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

using `scl enable` actually opens a new shell inside your current one, which is quite unclean, especially if done from a login script.

You should place, instead, in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
source /opt/rh/rh-nginx18/enable
```

or:

```
source scl_source enable rh-nginx18
```

The latter is more "elegant" as it is independent from the actual installation path.

This has the effect of loading the environment in your *current* shell.

Comment: this also works on amazon linux
    Linux ip-10-1-129-214 4.14.238-125.422.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 20 20:51:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 26):

[Redhat proposes placing a file in `/etc/profile.d`](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/527703), i.e. for python:

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/enablepython33.sh
#!/bin/bash
source scl_source enable python33
```

As this works for the devtools under centos for me you could try this.

Comment: This is what I do. I've created an `/etc/profile.d/scl_enable.sh` file with all of my scl files in that one file.

Answer (score -3):

I think you could add a line into your shell profile (e.g. ~/.bash_profile) to enable your scl of choice. For example,

> scl enable rh-nginx18 bash

EDIT: marked as spoiler since this is dangerous

Reload your profile or logout/login, and you should have access to your SCLs.

Comment: One problem with this is that your resulting bash is no longer a login shell. And you can't _make_ it a login shell. If you try, you'll fork bomb your system. This may work in some circumstances, but it's not the recommended method.

Comment: CAREFUL! Adding an scl command like the above just got me a "frozen" login because the script got stuck for some reason.  Have this page for a handy reference for when you get locked out: https://serverfault.com/questions/94503/login-without-running-bash-profile-or-bashrc

Comment: The accepted response is DANGEROUS, and should be somehow demoted or removed. Adding this so maybe people will notice it before forkbombing themselves :)

Comment: This fork bombed me and should be instantly removed.